# Leaflet map with jQuery autocomplete: fitBounds (click input) on selection?

Tags: leaflet, carto, jquery, carto-js

I'm trying to fire a click event on my search button and/or the input field as soon as a user selects something from the jQuery autocomplete `<li>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/grh2dLyw/1/

I'm not sure where to put this (`#zoominmap` is my button, `#columnsearch` the input field):

`document.getElementById('zoominmap').click();`

This is my code:

```
        function initAutocomplete() {
        function log( message ) {
          $( "<header>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
          $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#columnsearch" ).autocomplete({
          source: function( request, response ) {
                SQL_CLIENT.request({
                params: {
                    q: "SELECT name FROM " + dataSet + " where name Ilike '%" + request.term + "%'"},}).then(function(data) {
               response($.map(data.data.rows, function (item) { 
                  return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.name
                  }
                })
              )
            })
          },
          minLength: 3,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value );
                }
            });
        };

        // start jQuery autocomplete
        initAutocomplete();

        // search with AJAX
        $('#zoominmap').click(function () {
            if(previousSelection){
                map.removeLayer( previousSelection );   // if you're using Leaflet and map variable is named 'map'
            }
            input = $("#columnsearch").val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: `https://schwaebische.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=geojson&q=SELECT the_geom FROM ${dataSet} where name Ilike '${input}'`,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(response)
                map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds(), {maxZoom: maximumZoom, pan: {animate: true, duration: 0.5, easeLinearity: 0.25}});
            L.geoJson(response, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    return {color: "#FFF", opacity: 1, weight: 3};
                },
                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                    // remove this layer after another polygon is selected
                    previousSelection = layer;
                    }
                }).addTo(map);  
        }});
    })
```

Comment: Here's a write up with a working map, that does it a little different then you did, as an option. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/index.html

Comment: Cool - looks a lot smoother than mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [`select()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) function of the autocomplete widget quite correctly. However, you have to replace the typed-in value by the selected value if you want to process it further:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
  document.getElementById("columnsearch").value = ui.item.value //Set selected town
  document.getElementById('zoominmap').click();
}
```

Then the correct value is used in the `click()` function:

```
input = $("#columnsearch").val(); // "Stuttgart" rather than "stutt"
```

Comment: This works flawlessly - thank you very much! <3

Comment: Please accept my answer as solution. :)